# Make sure that this circuit is safe

Tags: infrared

I am going to feed 5V unresisted in through pin 3, ground out pin 2, and then read the output from pin 1. Would that be correct for [this IR sensor](http://www.karlssonrobotics.com/datasheets/Sensors/Infrared/tsop382.pdf)?

Also is this analog or digital output signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a clean 5v power supply, then yes this would be safe. But check the Application Circuit in the datasheet. They have R1 resistor for current limiting & C1 de-coupling capacitor for protection against power-supply noise:

```
R1 and C1 are recommended for protection against EOS.
Components should be in the range of 33 Ω < R1 < 1 kΩ,C1 > 0.1 µF
```

This is digital output signal. Check the internal circuit  & timing diagram to be sure. The internal switching BJT is there to provide digital output.